# Unit Test OnSuccess in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

```
public void onCreateAccountButtonClicked(Go99ApplicationconfigureApplication) {
    Log.i(TAG, " On create account button clicked");

    PasswordAndEmailValidator passwordAndEmailValidator = new PasswordAndEmailValidator();
    if (signUpView.getFirstName().isEmpty() || signUpView.getLastName().isEmpty() || signUpView.getEmailAddress().isEmpty() || signUpView.getPassword().isEmpty()
            || signUpView.getConfirmPassword().isEmpty()) {
        signUpView.showErrorMessage("Field empty");
        return;
    }

    if (!passwordAndEmailValidator.validatePassword(signUpView.getPassword())) {
        signUpView.showErrorMessage("Password must be a at least 6 characters long.");
        return;
    }

    if (!signUpView.getConfirmPassword().equals(signUpView.getPassword())) {
        signUpView.showErrorMessage("Passwords don't match");
        return;
    }

    RequestGSON requestGSON = new RequestGSON();
    requestGSON.setEmail(signUpView.getEmailAddress().replaceAll("\\s", "").toLowerCase());
    requestGSON.setFirstName(signUpView.getFirstName());
    requestGSON.setLastName(signUpView.getLastName());
    requestGSON.setPassword(signUpView.getPassword());

    creationService.createUser(requestGSON).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new SingleSubscriber<RestResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RestResponse value) {
            Object data = value.getData();
            String dataString = gson.toJson(data);
            CreatedUserObjectData createdUserObjectData = gson.fromJson(dataString, CreatedUserObjectData.class);
            signUpView.login(configureApplication, createdUserObjectData.getUserId(), signUpView.getEmailAddress().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""), signUpView.getPassword());

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {

        }
    });

}
```

I need to unit test this method. I am using Mockito. Please help me in testing the onSuccess() method as I'm using RxJava.

Comment: Need to verify SignUpView.login(...) is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to test your method. But, if your doubt is how test the RxJava part you can use TestSubscriber. You can check for a example [here](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2015/09/13/testing-rxjava-observables-subscriptions/).

You the problem is that you have a lot of code inside your onCreateAccountButtonClicked method, it has more than one responsibility... so there is a lot the test in the same method. Test the PasswordAndEmailValidator and creatingService separately is a better approach.

**Well, but you want to test onSuccess right?**

You can do this:

```
TestSubscriber<RestResponse> testSubs = new TestSubscriber<>();
creationService.createUser(requestGSON).subscribe(testSubs);

testSubs.assertCompleted()
```

You will probably need to mock you server. You can use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)

**Edit 1:**

If you want to test if a method in class get called do this:

**1 ->** As you are using RxJava your are going to need to inject a SchedulerProvider... so all your Schedulers are immediate.

Like this:

```
public class ImmediateSchedulerProvider {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Scheduler computation() {
        return Schedulers.immediate();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Scheduler io() {
        return Schedulers.immediate();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Scheduler ui() {
        return Schedulers.immediate();
    }
}
```

And the you inject this class in the RxJava function to be tested. This way you are always staying in the same thread, so you won't finish your test without a response.

Ok, second step now.

**2 ->** Inject a mock of your view that you would like to test. It's signUpView right? So instantiate your class like this:

```
@Mock
SighUpView sighUpView

@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Then call do your test and use the method Mokito.verify(T t)

**3 ->**

```
@Test
public void someTest(){

//Inject your mock ImeddiateScheculerProvider here or elsewhere. 
mSomeClass.onCreateAccountButtonClicked(mGo99ApplicationconfigureApplication, mImmediateSchudelerProvider.

//You must verify that your method was called with correct parameters!
Mockito.verify(sighUpView).login(configureApplication, createdUserObjectData.getUserId(), signUpView.getEmailAddress().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""), signUpView.getPassword());
}
```

Well, that is it. Use this as an example and adapt to your needs.

You can check [this repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture), by Google, if you need a more complete implementation.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to verify the below code is getting called : 

signUpView.login(configureApplication, createdUserObjectData.getUserId(), signUpView.getEmailAddress().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""), signUpView.getPassword());

Comment: Please if you can suggest anyting

Comment: yes, I have a suggestion. Check my edit. I hope it helps you.